# Export single or limit the no of products for export Magento2.4

Tags: magento2, product, export, importexport

In Magento, export functionality is there a way to export only a single product or limit the product export to 5 or 10. As I have more than 30,000 products as of now in my Magento.

But I only need certain products details in CSV.

Comment: In the Entity Attributes section when exporting you can enter the SKUs you want to export

Comment: actuallu writing of 30000 sku is also not feasible

Comment: If you want to export many products, you can choose the ID (for example, export the IDs from 1 -> 1000).